# LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble

Tags: compiling, pandoc, preamble

Running this shell skript:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
FILE=$1
pandoc --top-level-division=chapter -V geometry:"margin=0.8in, landscape" --toc -s $FILE -o ${FILE%.*}.pdf
```

with this minimal LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

gives me:

> ```
> Error producing PDF.
> ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...
>
> l.64 \documentclass
> ```

Any hints on this? I am new to LaTeX and have no clue why this is not working.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use pandoc to convert a LaTeX file to PDF. Instead, use LaTeX to do this: `pdflatex file`. The script you've written should work for converting a Markdown file to PDF. (Pandoc uses LaTeX to create the PDF but you don't have to write any LaTeX code for basic documents.)

Comment: In other words, if you run Pandoc on a LaTeX file in this way, it will create *another* LaTeX file with the necessary preamble and then include your LaTeX file inside it, which is why you are getting this error: the document Pandoc is creating includes your preamble commands in the body, not the preamble.

Comment: What did you do in the end, Michael?

Comment: Solution was using pandoc the correct way. Not mixing it with LaTeX code. As you guys told me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a misunderstanding. If you have got a kind of TeX system running (usually texlive or MiKTeX), save your LaTeX-file as (e.g.) foo.tex and run `pdflatex foo.tex` and you'll probably get `foo.pdf`as result.

`pdflatex --help` displays help in a nutshell.